# Checking a valid company or university email address

Tags: php, email

I want to check a email address whatever it is a company email address like from some company(xyz@stackoverflow.com) or educational institute etc or not. for example I can refer "Yammer" site. They are not taking general email address like yahoo or gmail or any other public email address for registration. I can only register with my university email address not others. How do they check this. I want to do similar things with PHP.

Any Idea or suggestion will be very helpful for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I put `saifuddin.sarker@somefakeschool.edu` is that valid because of the `.edu`? Or do you need to validate `somefakeschool.edu` as an actual educational institute?

Comment: Actual  i go to yammer.com and try to register there with my normal email address but cant. after puting my university email it works. But you have very good question. I tried your example and they accept it ;) that means they have some predefined domain name like yahoo , gmail etc and they just check those, Am i right?

Comment: Yeah, a blacklist would seem like a suitable approach

Comment: In Italy all schools has a .gov.it domain.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are lists of all universities worldwide (even delivered by wikipedia) - and there is also a commercial register (e.g. [this one](https://www.handelsregister.de/rp_web/mask.do?Typ=n) for Germany) where every company has to register. You may have to check against such databases (maybe you can also benefit of the whois information for the domain-name)...

EDIT: If you want to go the other way round you may have to trust a list like [this](https://github.com/willwhite/freemail/blob/master/data/free.txt).

Comment: Is there any way to check the list of company's who has email service like yahoo or gmail? :) Just get list of gmail.com or yahoo.com or web.de etc

Comment: Thanks for the answer, So far i will consider the free email list but still looking for better solution :) . Up vote for you

Answer (score 0):

You can validate this :

```
if(!preg_match('/^([\w-\.]+@(?=domain.com)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/',youremailaddress))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. my question was different. please check https://www.yammer.com .You cannot register there with your gmail or yahoo email address or other free email service. You need either your company email address or educational institute email address. How they do that? There are millions of institute or company, i can not check for each.

Comment: But you can check for free email service :^)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Do you have any idea to check the list of free email service :) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a "@domain.com" is in_array.
I suppose that there isn't an archive which lists mail addresses and domains of all organizations and college.

So:

```
$array_banned = array('gmail.com','yahoo.com','ymail.com', etc);
$array_white  = array('mrdoe@gmail.com');
$domain = substr(strrchr($email, "@"), 1);
if(!in_array($domain,$array_banned) || in_array($domain, $array_white)) {
  // OK, your code here
} else {
  echo 'Sorry, your email address has been excluded. If you want to use your email address please contact admin';
  // so you can insert requested mail in the white-listed array
}
```

Otherwise, you can use this [classes](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/13-PHP-Determine-if-a-given-e-mail-address-is-valid-.html) that do something similar, but add an SMTP validation